# Using vim regex to delete an entire line if it contains a period AND doesn't contain certain characters

Tags: regex, vim

I'm using vim and I'd like to delete an entire line that has a period (.) BUT doesn't have the following characters :, ö, ä, ë

```
good. bad # gets deleted
göod.     # does not get deleted
bäd. goëd # does not get deleted
go:od.    # does not get deleted
```

Below is the regex statement I'm using.  I'm using a substitute statement because I'd like to confirm each deletion, but I'm open to any solution (ie `%g//d`).

```
%s/\.\n//c
```

Comment: Recent Vims add the logipat plugin. You can then use something like this: `LP "\." & !("[:äöü]")`

Answer (score 1):

This is about as simple as I can get it. Just a basic check for a fullstop, and make sure that everything before and after it (on that line) isn't an alt character. Note, you may need to replace the leading `^` and trailing `$` with `\n` or perhaps add another flag to the commandline to make this find it per-row.

```
^[^:öäë]*\.[^:öäë]*$
```

Or translated for use in VIM (kudos to Sundeep):

```
:g/^[^:öäë]*\.[^:öäë]*$/d
```

Example: https://regex101.com/r/98tOtz/4

Comment: this translates to `:g/^[^:öäë]*\.[^:öäë]*$/d` for OP

Comment: On a side note: Vim has its own syntax for regexps.  In the vast majority of cases testing Vim regexps against `https://regex101.com/` is useless.

Comment: Thanks for that @Sundeep. Edited into answer, kudos to you.

Answer (score 1):

@Addison's answer is fine for this particular case; here's a more general solution in case the positive match isn't as trivial as `.`:

```
/^\%(.*[:öäë]\)\@!.*\./
```

This asserts a non-match `\@!` from the beginning of the line `^` anywhere after of the bad characters `.*[:öäë]`, then matches (again from the beginning, as the assertion did not consume any characters) a literal period `.*\.`

You can use this regular expression both in `:global` as well as `:substitute`:

```
:%s/^\%(.*[:öäë]\)\@!.*\..*\n//c
```